# How can I get Vim to give me different tab settings for crontab?

Tags: cron, vim

I would like to be able to keep the temporal expressions in my crontab neatly organized in columns, with a key above every 5 or so entries, like so:

```
#m  h   dom mon dow command
30  6   *   *   *   /bin/bash -l -c 'blah blah blah'

5   10  *   *   *   /bin/bash -l -c 'yada yada yada'
```

Of course that breaks when I have a complex temporal expression like this:

```
5 0,8,10,12,14,16,20,22 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'blah blah blah'
```

but that's okay.  Cron is what it is, and there's only so much we can do.

I normally use spaces, with an indent of 2, but this seems to be clearly a job for tabs.

I've added this to the top of my crontab

```
# vim: set tabstop=4 noexpandtab :
```

but when I hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, it gives me 2 spaces, and the second time I hit it it gives me a tab (which replaces the 2 spaces).  If I type a character and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, I get one space first, and hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> again will replace that with a tab character.  If I type 2 characters and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, it works as expected.

What am I missing?

(This is on a server used by others where I work, where we log in as ourselves and then `sudo` to an app account.  The `~/.vimrc` is unfortunately something that was created by another user, so the configurations there are not things I'm familiar with, but I can take the liberty to change them if necessary.)

Comment: Doesn't the `set` form of modelines require a colon at the end? Does any of it work?

Comment: @MichaelHomer oh you're right, but even after fixing that it still behaves the same way...

Comment: Do modelines work in other files? What does `:set modeline?` print out?

Comment: it prints `modeline` and `:set modelines` prints out `modelines=5`

Comment: `# vim: set tabstop=4 noexpandtab:` works for me with `crontab -e` and `vi /etc/crontab` etc.   Maybe check to see if any of your vimrc files has an `autocmd` that changes settings for files like /tmp/crontab.*, /etc/cron* or similar. 
 Search for lines beginning with something like `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /tmp/cron*`.   If so, fix it.  If not, maybe you can use an autocmd yourself to do what you want.